# having trouble loading a html partial into ng-view in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4

I am having a problem loading a html file into a ng-view directive and when the page is trying  to load it into ng-view the page crash. Here is the code of the of the page to get the html fragment:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    {{HTML::style('css/bootstrap-theme.css')}}
    {{HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css')}}
    {{HTML::script('js/angular.min.js')}}
    {{HTML::script('js/angular.route.js')}}
    {{HTML::script('js/courtFinderApp.js')}}
</head>

<body ng-app="courtfinderApp">

   <div ng-view>


   </div>

</body>
```

Also here is the angularjs code:

```
var app = angular.module('courtfinderApp',['ngRoute']);


app.config(function($interpolateProvider){

//change the default expression template for angularJS
 $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
 $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');


});



app.config(function($routeProvider) {

            $routeProvider.when('/login',{

                 templateUrl: 'partials/login.php',

                });

        });
```

what I am doing wrong and thanks in advance

Comment: What's your routing setup on the Laravel backend? Are you routing to the above html page as your root? i.e. `Route::get('/', function(){ return View::make('index'); });` ?

Comment: *the page crash*: what are you doing to try loading the partial, and what happens *precisely*. Include the error messages you get.

Comment: My routing setup is Route::controller('account,'AccountController'); and the method in the controller is getSignIn()

Comment: @JBNizet the error I  got in the console was RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded